# Pass along jsp:param tags from custom tag to a jsp:include tag?

Tags: jsp, include, jsp-tags, tagfile

I'm trying to create a tag file that in a way "extends" the `<jsp:include>` tag. Basically I want to add custom logic so that in certain circumstances it will include a different file. I got it working fine for regular `<jsp:include>` tags, but I'm still struggling when there are `<jsp:param>` tags in the picture.

What I want to be able to do is this:

In the normal jsp code, **main.jsp**:

```
<custom:jsp-include page="include.jsp">
    <jsp:param name="a" value="b"/>
    <jsp:param name="x" value="y"/>
</custom:jsp-include>
```

And in the tag file, **customInclude.tag**:

```
...

<jsp:include page="${someJspFile}">
    //SOMETHING-UNKNOWN-HERE
</jsp:include>
```

And the expected result is that the file in the variable **someJspFile** is called, with all the parameters defined in the **main.jsp**. Ie parameter **a=b** and **x=y** in this case.

But I don't know how to make this happen. I have tried using `<jsp:doBody var="bodyContent"/>`, and then put `${bodyContent}` inside the `<jsp:include>`, but that just results in an error. The error depends on the type of **body-content** I have defined for the tag file. If I set it to **"tagdependent"** then the error is:

> Expecting "jsp:param" standard action with "name" and "value"
>   attributes

...and if I set it to **"scriptless"**, then the error is for the main.jsp code, with the error:

> The jsp:param action must not be used outside the jsp:include,
>   jsp:forward, or jsp:params elements

Surely there must be a way to achieve this? Or of a more more general point of view, there must be a way to pass along the body content as untouched, from one tag (my custom tag file in this case) to another (`<jsp:include>` in this case), right?

Note that it's not specifically the possibility to put `${bodyContent}` inside the `<jsp:include>` tag that I am after, since I can see how that could be considered as an eval type function if it would work, and it's not the possibility of doing eval that I am after. Maybe there is some special placeholder or similar, that I can put inside the `<jsp:include>` tag, that will make it work just as if I had copy pasted the `<jsp:param>` tags from **main.jsp** into the body of the `<jsp:include>` in **customInclude.tag**?

Regards

/Jimi